# How to return early in a GNU C statement expression

Tags: c, macros

I want to express logic like this in a statement expression

```
if (!pass_check) {
  return 1;
}
if (!pass_check2) {
  return 2;
}
return 0;
```

My macro does some checking before doing its actual thing. For reasons, I can't use a function here; it must be a macro

```
#define FOO ({ \
  if (!pass_check) { \
    return 1; \
  } \
  if (!pass_check2) { \
    return 2; \
  } \ 
  return 0; \
})
```

However, I can't seem to use `return` in macros, only the value of the last subexpression is returned as stated in the [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html). How can I make this have the intended effect?

Edit: added minimal working example. This macro will not compile,
but this is how I intend to use it. The idea is that I want to run some checks before foo() runs, and I want to accomplish this by wrapping foo() in a macro:

```
int pass_check1(int i) {
    if (i > 10) return 1;
    return 0;
}

int pass_check2(int i) {
    if (i < 0) return 1;
    return 0;
}

int foo(int i) {
  // foo must be called only after the previous checks pass
  // the checks above are examples only, the idea is that I should
  // be able to prepend any number pass_checkN checks before foo()
  // is called

  return 0;
}

// FOO should return 1 if either check fails, else whatever foo() returns.
#define FOO(i) (     \
  if (!pass_check(i)) { \
    return 1; \
  } \
  if (!pass_check2(i)) { \
    return 2; \
  } \ 
  foo(i); \
})

int main() {
    int ret = FOO(i);
}
```

Comment: `return (pass_check ? (pass_check2 ? 0 : 2) : 1);`

Comment: In C++ you could use a proper lambda if you want that kind of `return`. But normally I've found it's useful for a statement-expression to *actually* return, e.g. for a rust-style `try!` macro.

Comment: You are aware that the `return` is irrelevant for the macro and will always act to return from whatever function the macro is used in, aren't you? Please show a [mre] of how you intend to use the macro. That should clarify your assumptions and potential misunderstandings. My guess is something like `printf("%d\n", FOO);` by which I mean to demonstrate that I think you don't want any return in your macro (in contrast to the proposal by @AdrianMole )

Comment: @Yunnosch thanks for telling me about return, I was not aware it returns the outer function. I don't want the outer the function to return, just the "inner" function of the macro. I added a MRE.

Comment: Your "minimum" example that you added would compile if you fix the errors, but it won't behave the way you want. https://tio.run/##hVLLTsMwELznKwZxSVChj2uBIxIX@gGAkJNsWgvHjuwkUFX99rC2Qx@oEjlldzIzu7MpbtdFMQxSt2iEcx/FhorPeeprmWGXgB9ZIZV4xHyWwVLbWY35MiBjNVsm@yQ511hc0rjH/xKVMafU6dR3UHeuRU4ohFJUwmi1hahasmg3hMZSL03nEKxdGCNyPTo2RW56grAE@hZ1o8gFmUn4RpYkIB2/ixbPcBvTqTJKsKvIFaE13qchXULoLXRX52x/3Pjl1yinyrCLXySLEiwcB0@SPxsz@LRajX6HaHxcJHkuGzVRCancBKQc4YtHpJ6hYDBy3F1yXVIlNXm9lMNLdz5evCUx/Kuz82YcboBwPEeo95cIi0uExSkhHC3znX0Wz1gLqeMdJ7yDsLgRdt2/vh9@CIZYCQ/jvJzGMPwA

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need your macro to use nested ternaries, as follows:

```
#define FOO (!pass_check ? 1 : (!pass_check2 ? 2 : 0))
```

As you noted, the "return" value of a macro is just the value of the last expression, and this will do what you want.

Comment: You already have my upvote. I recommend however to explain the difference of "returning" to implementing an expression, in order to help OP with their seemingly fundamental misunderstanding of macros and preprocessor....